# MongoDB updateMany is not a function

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb 3.6.3

> db.version()
>       3.6.3

I have test collection:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c582787e504df9ad201ba77"), "val" : 0.25 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c582789e504df9ad201ba78"), "val" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c58278be504df9ad201ba79"), "val" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c58278fe504df9ad201ba7a"), "val" : 11122 }
```

And I want to divide all values. Due for this I've tried to use [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)

```
> db.test.updateMany({}, {$mul: {val: 0.5}})
2019-02-04T17:08:27.548+0500 TypeError: Property 'updateMany' of object local.test is not a function
> db.test.update({}, {$mul: {val: 0.5}}, {multi:true})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 4, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 4 })
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c582787e504df9ad201ba77"), "val" : 0.125 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c582789e504df9ad201ba78"), "val" : 0.5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c58278be504df9ad201ba79"), "val" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c58278fe504df9ad201ba7a"), "val" : 5561 }
```

Why there is no updateMany function?

Comment: use `db.update({}, {$mul: {val: 0.5}}, {multi: true})`
read more about `update` here (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update)

btw. I think you have to use `$set` operator. otherwise, all data will rewrited.

Comment: @Gor Yes, rewrite all data that the aim. I'm just curious, why the is no updateMany

Comment: What is the version of your mongo cli?

Comment: @Ashish 2.6.10 that the answer

Comment: @Petr As I remember, updateMany function is available only for mongo shell version >3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updateMany has been introduced in version 3.2 since you're using mongo shell with version 2.6.10, it's missing there. You need to update your CLI and it should work as expected.